# Raspberry Pi Zero I2C pull up + GY-521

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm trying to talk via I2C to the gyro sensor MPU6050 which sits on a GY 521 board. But i can't get the device being detect.

I tested another i2c device (EEPROM) and got the device address detected. So i guess it has to be a hardware problem.

As far as i could find out:

- RPi has a 1.8k pullup resistor on SDA and SLC already on board
- my GY 521 also has also a pullup resistor (2.2k) on each line on board

Could the resistors be the problem? A good resistor value in sum would be around 5k on each line?

(The wiring should be ok, there are a lot of instructions around the net and i've checked it multiple times. I use 5v on the GY521 since it has a voltage converter)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was bad soldering.

For the record:
Using the RPi pullups in combination with the breakout board pullups works for me.